# Transparent Terminal sometimes not working

Tags: command-line, konsole

I normally have my konsole configured to have a transparent background color, but it's sometimes just not working ("This color scheme uses a transparent background which does not appear to be supported on your desktop"). I have a Nvidia GTX 1060 graphics card, in case that's important. What can I do to fix that?